# Infinitesimal generator of change of basis (Fock Space)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, density-operator, many-body, unitarity

I'm trying to find unitary transformation and prove that the infinitesimal generator for a change of basis with spatial depedency $$|\vec{r} \rangle \rightarrow e^{i \theta  (\vec{r}) }|\vec{r}\rangle $$ is the density operator $\hat{\rho} = \hat{\psi}^{\dagger}(\vec{r}) \hat{\psi}(\vec{r})$

My attempt was:

$$\hat{U}{(\theta(\vec{r})}) \hat{\psi}(\vec{r}) \hat{U(\theta(\vec{r}))}^{\dagger} = e^{-i\theta(\vec{r})} \hat{\psi}(\vec{r}) \iff \\ \iff  \hat{\psi}(\vec{r}) - i \theta(\vec{r})[G,\hat{\psi}(\vec{r})] = \hat{\psi}(\vec{r}) - i \theta(\vec{r})\hat{\psi}(\vec{r})  $$

Thus,

$$ [G,\hat{\psi}(\vec{r})] = \hat{\psi}(\vec{r}) \rightarrow  G = \hat{N} $$

Which is not the solution.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The step where you went wrong is in writing
$$\hat{U}(\theta(\vec{r}))=1-i\theta(\vec{r})G$$
for infinitesimal transformations. This would imply $U(\theta(\vec{r}))$ is an operator-valued function of $\vec{r}$ instead of a single unitary operator. In reality, there should be a separate generator for each point in space:
$$\hat{U}(\theta(\vec{r}))=1-i\int d^3r \theta(\vec{r})G(\vec{r}).$$
Then you get
$$\left[\int d^3r' \theta(\vec{r}')G(\vec{r}'),\hat{\psi}(\vec{r})\right]=\theta(\vec{r})\hat{\psi}(\vec{r})$$
$$\implies \int d^3r' \theta(\vec{r}')\left[G(\vec{r}'),\hat{\psi}(\vec{r})\right]=\theta(\vec{r})\hat{\psi}(\vec{r}).$$
You can plug in $G(\vec{r})=\hat{\psi}^\dagger(\vec{r})\hat{\psi}(\vec{r})$ at this point.
$$\theta(\vec{r})\hat{\psi}(\vec{r})=\int d^3r' \theta(\vec{r}')\left[\hat{\psi}^\dagger(\vec{r}')\hat{\psi}(\vec{r}'),\hat{\psi}(\vec{r})\right]$$
$$=\int d^3r' \theta(\vec{r}')\left(\hat{\psi}^\dagger(\vec{r}')\{\hat{\psi}(\vec{r}'),\hat{\psi}(\vec{r})\} - \{\hat{\psi}^\dagger(\vec{r}'),\hat{\psi}(\vec{r})\}\hat{\psi}(\vec{r}')\right)$$
$$=\int d^3r' \theta(\vec{r}')\left(\hat{\psi}^\dagger(\vec{r}')\cdot 0 - \delta^{(3)}(\vec{r}-\vec{r}')\hat{\psi}(\vec{r}')\right)$$
$$=\theta(\vec{r})\hat{\psi}(\vec{r})$$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

If you have $\{\psi(r),\psi^\dagger (r')\}= \delta(r-r')$and want a transformation $\psi(r)\to e^{i\theta(r)}\psi(r)$, or its infinitesimal version
$$
[\psi(r),G]=  \theta(r)  \psi(r),
$$
you need to take $G= \int \theta(r') \psi^\dagger(r')\psi(r)\,dr'$.  To get this you need to use the commutator-anticommutator identity
$$
[A,BC]=\{A,B\}C-B\{A,C\}.
$$

Comment: How I can I prove that? Why do you get that correspondence for the commutator? @mikestone

Comment: I added the key step.

Comment: I'm going to try and do the calculations! Just one more question, am I doing something wrong in my attempt because I don't get that in the commutation relation. How can I prove that generator is that one?

Comment: Are you familiar with $e^{A}Be^{-A}= B+[A,B]+\frac 12 [A,[A,B]]+\ldots$?

Comment: Yes, thank you! However, isn't the commutation relation wrong?

Comment: Which one? I did not check signs carefully, but I think the $[A,BC]$ one is correct.

Comment: I mean the commutation relation for the field operators, I think in this exercise we are using bosonic field operators, but the commutation relation that you use its for fermionic field operators? Is the proof equal with   bosonic field operators?

Comment: Ah. You did not say.  Using $\psi$ rather than $\phi$b usually means bosonic, but the final result is tha same. Remember that commutators act as (anti)-derivations in a rather consistent way.